# Joining asp_Users db tables in LINQ using asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I am working on an example asp.net project using MVC, but my database is a live one which I can't make changes to (technically it's the test version of this database but my point is changes to the database aren't possible).

I use the UserID from the asp_Users table to store who makes changes to various aspects of the system, and I want to start showing the user name in various front-end tables, but how do I link the tables to get this user name?

So to clarify, I'm going to want to do this for several tables throughout the system so I was hoping I could do it using LINQ.

I can get the info I want from using the join query, but how do I pass this to my View to use?

```
        var plans = from users in db.aspnet_Users
                           join import in db.Plan_Imports
                           on users.UserId.ToString()
                           equals import.User_ID

                           select new
                           {
                               Date = import.Date,
                               UserName = users.UserName
                           };
```

Sample tables

**asp_Users**

UserID

UserName

...

**table1**

ID

field1

field2

...

User_ID  <--- ref to asp_Users

**table2**

ID

field1

field2

...

User_ID  <--- ref to asp_Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by Shyju worked perfectly, and it wasn't too complex to do, however I decided that I didn't think using LINQ was appropriate in this case as the code was getting out of hand for what should be a simple call.

What I did instead was use a stored procedure to get the information, and saved it to a complex object which I passed to my view.

The code is now much neater and easier to manage, as the code above became just

```
var plans = db.SP_SelectImports();
```

Read more about stored procedure mapping here: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/mapping-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

I would create a **ViewModel** for each view.

ViewModel is just a POCO class

```
public class PlanViewModel
{
  public string UserName { set;get;}
  public DateTime ImportDate { set;get;}
}
```

Then Get the Data to this ViewModel/Collection of ViewModel using LINQ Projections from your query.

```
public ActionResutl Show()
{
   var plans = (from users in db.aspnet_Users
                           join import in db.Plan_Imports
                           on users.UserId.ToString()
                           equals import.User_ID

                           select new PlanViewModel
                           {
                               ImportDate = import.Date,
                               UserName = users.UserName
                           }).ToList();
   return View(plans);    
}
```

Now Lets make our view strongly typed to a collection of our `PlanViewModel`

```
@model List<PlanViewModel>
@foreach(var plan in Model)
{
  <p>@plan.UserName</p>
  <p>@plan.ImportDate.ToString()</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it did work perfectly but there was an issue with the toString() method as I'm comparing a guid and a string. I resolved this by changing the top line to db.aspnet_Users.AsEnumerable()